# Bootcamp Yosemite: How to Install windows 7 with DVD

Tags: macos, bootcamp, install, windows

I was wondering is it possible to Install Windows7 with a bootable DVD?

**On apple web site:**

> When you purchase Windows, it either comes as a disk image file (ISO)
>   or as an installation disc. If your copy of Windows came on a DVD, you
>   should create a disk image of your installation disc.

Why should I make an ISO when I have an original windows dvd and my mac is also have an optical drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer really depends on the model of your Mac. Generally, if your Mac came with an internal optical drive, you probably should install using the DVD. Also, the Boot Camp Assistant is a good source to answer your question. If the option to create a Windows install USB flash drive is available, then you probably will need to create an iso file from your DVD. Start the Boot Camp Assistant application and continue through the windows until you get the "Select Tasks" window. Your answer will be based on the options that appear.